# How to split() a delimited string to a List<String>

Tags: c#, .net, list, arraylist

I had this code:

```
    String[] lineElements;       
    . . .
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lineElements = line.Split(',');
                . . .
```

but then thought I should maybe go with a List instead. But this code:

```
    List<String> listStrLineElements;
    . . .
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                listStrLineElements = line.Split(',');
. . .
```

...gives me, "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'*"

Answer (score 468, accepted):

`string.Split()` returns an array - you can convert it to a list using `ToList()`:

```
listStrLineElements = line.Split(',').ToList();
```

Note that you need to import `System.Linq` to access the `.ToList()` function.

Comment: Probably should mention here that you have to be using namespace System.Linq

Comment: @sairfan `listStrLineElements = line?.Split(',').ToList();`

Answer (score 71):

Either use:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(array);
```

or from LINQ:

```
List<string> list = array.ToList();
```

Or change your code to not rely on the specific implementation:

```
IList<string> list = array; // string[] implements IList<string>
```

Answer (score 16):

Include using namespace `System.Linq`

```
List<string> stringList = line.Split(',').ToList();
```

you can make use of it with ease for iterating through each item.

```
foreach(string str in stringList)
{

}
```

`String.Split()` returns an array, hence convert it to a list using `ToList()`

Answer (score 6):

Just u can use  with `using System.Linq;`

```
List<string> stringList = line.Split(',')     // this is array
 .ToList();     // this is a list which you can loop in all split string
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this line:

```
List<string> stringList = line.Split(',').ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

This will read a csv file and it includes a csv line splitter that handles double quotes and it can read even if excel has it open.

```
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> LoadCsvAsDictionary(string path)
    {
        var result = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fs);

        string line;

        int n = 0;
        List<string> columns = null;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var values = SplitCsv(line);
            if (n == 0)
            {
                columns = values;
            }
            else
            {
                var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
                    if (i < values.Count)
                        dict.Add(columns[i], values[i]);
                result.Add(dict);
            }
            n++;
        }

        file.Close();
        return result;
    }

    private List<string> SplitCsv(string csv)
    {
        var values = new List<string>();

        int last = -1;
        bool inQuotes = false;

        int n = 0;
        while (n < csv.Length)
        {
            switch (csv[n])
            {
                case '"':
                    inQuotes = !inQuotes;
                    break;
                case ',':
                    if (!inQuotes)
                    {
                        values.Add(csv.Substring(last + 1, (n - last)).Trim(' ', ','));
                        last = n;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            n++;
        }

        if (last != csv.Length - 1)
            values.Add(csv.Substring(last + 1).Trim());

        return values;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] thisArray = myString.Split('/');//<string1/string2/string3/--->     
List<string> myList = new List<string>(); //make a new string list    
myList.AddRange(thisArray);
```

Use `AddRange` to pass `string[]` and get a string list.

Answer (score 3):

I use this extension method which handles `null` input and also removes the redundant **white spaces**.

```
public static List<string> CsvToList(this string csv)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(csv))
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }

    return csv.Split(',').Select(item => item.Trim()).ToList();
}
```

Note that if the input CSV is: "Apple, Orange, Pear" we want to get rid of the white spaces after the commas.

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this
var countryDBs="myDB,ukDB";

var countryDBsList = countryDBs.Split(',').ToList();

```
        foreach (var countryDB in countryDBsList)
        {
           
        }
```