# I have a csv file whose contents is like as the following. How I can convert it to collection of List<string> dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, webforms

This csv file has lots of rows but all the rows doesn't have the equal number of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the string split method.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx.

Suppose you read your csv file into a string, you can split the string on line breaks into multiple strings.  You'll create a new list for each new line string. You'll split each line on whatever you have for your delimiter, then add those values to your list.

Edit:  here is a similar question [How to split() a delimited string to a List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263695/how-to-split-a-delimited-string-to-a-liststring)

Comment: Could you please give some code sample first reading the file, then split and adding it to the list

Comment: To read the file:  TextReader myReader = File.OpenText(filename); So, I think you can actually split the lines of the file into strings with the line reader method: string myString = myReader.ReadLine();  Then split on your delimeter List<string> myValues = myString.split(',');  Here is a good reference on using the readline to add to create a list for your strings before you split the values http://www.dotnetperls.com/readline

Answer (score 2):

For dealing complex CSV files it is better to use a reliable solution, See this http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

It's easy to use simple like this

```
var csv = new CsvReader( textReader );
var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>().ToList();
```