# Define Characters to Display in List<String>

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, list

[image]

I'm trying to organize information in a text file and I thought a good way to do it would be to define each line of the file as its own List Item and then cut up each List entry by commas but I can't figure out how to parse or split the list items to use them later on.

This reads the file and returns a list with five entries:

```
    public static List<String> ImportVehicalList() {

        List<String> vehiclesAndOptions = new List<string>();
        StreamReader sr = null;

        try { // Attempt to open text file

            String filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/srcDocuments/modelsAndOptions.txt");
            String modelOptions; // Line to be added to List

            using (sr = new StreamReader(filePath)) {

                while ((modelOptions = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {

                    // Tried to split it before creating the list but
                    // this did not work.
                    //modelOptions.Split(',').ToList<String>();
                    vehiclesAndOptions.Add(modelOptions);

                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { } // File Not Found Catch
        finally { try { sr.Close(); } catch (Exception ex) { } } // Cannot close the reader

        return vehiclesAndOptions;
    }
```

This is how I'm loading the list into an asp.net drop-down list. I was hoping to split the list here so that only the model shows in the drop down.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    List<String> vehicalList = new List<string>();
    vehicalList = Utils.ImportVehicalList();

    foreach (String i in vehicalList) {

        ddlModels.Items.Add(i);
        //Response.Write(i);

    }

    // Binds the list to drop down menu ddlModels
    //ddlModels.DataSource = vehicalList;
    //ddlModels.DataBind();


}
```

There are a lot of post on here for parsing information and truthfully, I'm not very proficient with it and I have yet to find a solution that I am able to implement using my code. Here are some of the sources I've looked into:

[How to split() a delimited string to a List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263695/how-to-split-a-delimited-string-to-a-liststring)

https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-string

Is it even possible to parse a list item on a comma or can this only be done by splitting a string first and then adding each item to a list?

Comment: Based on the the input data displayed in the image, what is the expected output?

Comment: I get the output that I expect to receive, the trouble is manipulating the list entry after the method has been called. If you look at the image provided you will see all of the entries but the first is:

Corvette, JATO, Power Moonroof, Leather Interior, 6-speed transmission, 8-track player, 200mph Tires

I would like to be able to cut up the list item so that I can control what items are seen in the drop down and list boxes, for example selecting the Corvette would give you all of the options listed with it.

Comment: Instead of `Corvette, JATO, Power Moonroof, Leather Interior, 6-speed transmission, 8-track player, 200mph Tires ` in the first item, what is should be? I am asking again coz I am not getting what is your expectation from the code.

Comment: Do you mean something like `ddlModels.Items.Add(i.Split(',').First());` ?

Comment: So lets say that I have a string with that list item above, I could use .Split(',') to separate each item but for what I am trying to do I thought it would be easier to segregate each car with its respective features in a list rather than creating list items for every comma, is it possible to achieve something similar like a vehicaleAndOptions.Split(',') that would work with a type of List<String>?

Comment: Sure, `Split()` returns an array, just use `vehicleAndoptions.Split(',').AsList<string>()` . If you'd like to start at the second item, which I suspect is the case, then you can just use skip, so something like: `vehicleAndoptions.Split(',').Skip(1).AsList<string>()`

Comment: ... Is there a way to chose items other than the first? i.split(','). Second());?

Comment: @shockmec see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is again string.split, when you are looping. So from what I understand, each line contains a model with attributes like so:
`Model, attribute, attribute, attribute`

And you want for each model a list of attributes. In your case this becomes:

```
string[] arr = vehicleAndoptions.Split(',');
string model = arr[0];// or arr.First(); if you prefer linq
List<string> attributes = arr.Skip(1).AsList<string>();
```

Comment: I enjoy coding but I hate how I can spend hours trying different combinations of things with no luck. I'm able to select an item in my list using something very similar to what you've posted. 

            ddlModels.Items.Add(i.Split(',').Skip(1).First());

Thank you for the help.

Comment: glad to be of help