# How to insert to arrays with some factors in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a `Console.ReadLine();` and I input `1 2 3` with spaces between.
Then I want the numbers to be saved in an array like this `{1,2,3}`
basically I want to take the spaces and tell c# to make them Index seperators.

```
anyvar = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Int[] arrayvar = {}; 
Console.WriteLine(arrayvar[1]); // expects 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Splitting Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559121/c-sharp-splitting-strings)

Comment: Take the string input, do `.Split( ' ' )` to get an array of the numbers split by space and `.Select( x => Convert.ToInt32( x ) ).ToArray()` to get an array of actual numbers. I suggest trying `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32` as someone could enter anything in the console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split() a delimited string to a List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263695/how-to-split-a-delimited-string-to-a-liststring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
// Set array elements from Command Line by splitting the Command Line and parsing to Int 
var anyvar = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

// Display the array elements using the array index     
Console.WriteLine(anyvar[1]);
```

Comment: btw does it work for lists and dictionaries , just asking

Comment: @BDGGR_Flayer It can very well work for the `List`  by chnaging the above code as   `Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToList();`. However Dictionary is a data structure based on key value pair you need to specify a key and then a value for that key, In which format will you be passing the data to be stored in a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D7Ot2k)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var anyvar = "1 2 3";
        int[] arrayvar = anyvar.Split(' ').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray(); 
        Console.WriteLine(arrayvar[1]); // expects 2 
    }
}
```