# C# string with comma separated numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, listboxitem

I have a series of numbers, comma separated, stored in SQL server.
These numbers are the IDs of a Listbox.
How can I select the Listboxes in C# based on the stored comma separated string?

```
CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "id";
CheckboxList1.DataTextField = "location_name";
CheckBoxList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
ChekBoxList1.DataBind();
```

The string is stored in SQL server table location, field toegang and the string looks like 34,656,43

Comment: Do something like `var MyList = "34,656,43".Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).OrderBy(x => x).ToList()`. Now you have an array of integers and can then check the correct checkboxes.

Comment: You might need another layer.   I would unpack them into a list and iterate the list to select the items.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263695/how-to-split-a-delimited-string-to-a-liststring

Comment: *"I have a series of numbers, comma separated, stored in SQL server."* Why not fix your design and *normalise* your data? That's the *real* solution. If you're storing a delimited list of numbers, the column *must* be defined as a string based datatype, and I suspect you don't have any kind of validation on your data to stop a value like `'four,5,pizza,12e'` being entered into the database.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to enter it as create a table in the database and split data into new table

```
create table Locations(Id int identity(1,1),location_name varchar(100))
```

| Id | location_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 |
| 2 | 656 |
| 3 | 43 |

If you can't, you can split both in the sql server and in C#

C#(Split)

```
string data = "123,254,147,741";
var _list= data.Split(',').ToList();
```

sql server(function STRING_SPLIT)
example 1:

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('123,254,147,741', ',');
```

example 2:

```
select id,value as location_nameNew,location_name
from Locations
cross apply (
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(location_name, ',')
)a
```